вывести цену товара в корзине произвольном месте
мне нужно вывести цену товара в корзине под заголовком (страница корзины, создана через шорткод, сайт создан с нуля)
function name_price(  )

{
$sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true, array() );
echo '<p>' . wc_price($sale) . '</p>';

}
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'name_price');
с помощью следующего кода выводится цена последнего товара. Если я правильно понимаю чтобы выводилась цена  конкретного товара нужен массив, как его сделать? (приложил скрин чтоб показать цену товара )
